# Unable to understand output using leave statement

Tags: sas

```
 data primes;
    length status $12.;
    do i=1 to 4;
    status='Prime';
      do j=2 to i-1;
      if mod(i, j) = 0 then do;
        status='Composite';
        leave; *exit loop;
    end;
end;
        output;
  end;
     run;

     proc print data = primes;
        run;
```

Above is the program that I ran and below is the output. I am unable to understand how the value of i when the numbers are prime. I have mentioned i should go till n-1 but in the output the value of i =n for primes. Can someone please help me understand this?

```
                Obs     status  i   j
                1   Prime       1   2   
                2   Prime       2   2
                3   Prime       3   3
                4   Composite   4   2
```

Answer (score 1):

If i=1 then the second loop is j=2 to 0 which means the loop never starts. The j loop never executes. You can add an explicit output or put statement to see this.